What format does a Postfix Milter use?
I am attempting to write a custom miller for postfix , but am not sure what format I need to use before I begin writing my logic.
So far, I have postfix sending mail to a miller with:
non_smtpd_milters = inet:12301@localhost

I then create a listening socket with:
nc -l 12301

The nc session is then active waiting for connection.
I then open a new terminal and start postfix
postfix start

Now, I send an email with postfix send mail
sendmail -t user@external.com

What I then see in my nc session is a string containing a capital O and the 'diamond question mark' symbol.
I am not sure how to interpret this output from nc.
I assumed that postfix, upon being passed mail via sendmail, would forward the mail onto the port listed by non_smtp_milters. This appears to occur as, when mail is sent, the characters appear in the nc session.
I then expected to either be presented with the mail headers and body in the nc session. Or, at least, some text I could use to figure out how to proceed. Instead, I am seeing the symbols I mention above.
What am I misunderstanding ? Can anyone explain what the significance of these symbols is ? How would I implement the input and output required for a custom milter ?

I suggest you look at the hex output & proceed from there. You'll find they are field separators.

It uses the Sendmail 'milter' protocol. (As in the original "Sendmail MTA" which Postfix's /usr/sbin/sendmail imitates.)
Sendmail "milters" are not pure data transform filters like sed/awk – they additionally receive envelope information and connection metadata (e.g. IP address of the SMTP client), and they can instruct the MTA to perform various actions beyond transforming the message data (e.g. they can request the MTA to immediately reject the message with a 4xx or 5xx code) – and as a result they need an interactive two-way protocol to communicate with the MTA.
The protocol is not entirely text-based; it uses binary framing (uint16 length prefixed packets), and some of the characters you see are binary values that were never meant to be interpreted as ASCII characters.
You can implement the protocol yourself, but there already are milter protocol libraries for many programming languages:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Sendmail::Milter
https://docs.rs/milter/latest/milter/
https://pymilter.org/

